# Selecting and caluclating area of 'planes' in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, stl-format

I am trying to calulate the area of a 'plane' of 3d object (.stl mesh object) `n` in [three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene). By selecting it with a mouse click.
For example this area:[image: example of 3d 'plane' that needs to be selected]

We know that all 'triangles' that make up the surface of the 'plane' (since it is an .stl) are attached at the same angle, if the angle changes in comparison to the last triangle, we know that this triangle is not part of the 'plane' anymore.

So knowing this is a property of the surface we are trying to calulate, we can use this in combination with some form of [three.js Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) to select and calculate an area (by adding all the area's of the triangles with the correct properties together).

For now, we don't need to worry about the size of the selected surface (for example trying to find a 'plane' on a curved surface wouldn't be valid, but we do not need to worry about that now)

How would I go about trying to find the area and 'plane' in three.js. Or more specifically, how do I start reading the .stl format's 'triangles'.

[Minimal working example of my current code](https://github.com/TjalleWired/three.js-stackoverflow) (with working .stl file included), it can be run using a simple live server, for example in VS Code using [Ritwick Dey's plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), no extra plugins/libraries needed, since it's 'normal' HTML/JS.

The only requirement is that we select the point we are trying to calculate in three.js and give the area (selected triangles) a different colour, in three.js, when they are selected. Any other calculations needed could be done in some kind of backend (Python, Node.js or anything else really), but I see no obvious way of transporting such complicated data between programs.

My minimal reproduction code, see my abovementioned github link for the .stl file used in my picture:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stackoverflow Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/render.css">
</head>

<body>



    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script>
        function init() {


            // Setup some basic stuff
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);


            // Setup Camera 
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);

            // Setup renerer and add to page
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            }

            // Setup Camera Position
            camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
            camera.position.x = 800;
            camera.position.y = 100;
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            // Add Camera Control through orbit.js
            let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

            // Add some basic ambient lighting (Does light all parts equally and does not cast shadows)
            hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 20);
            scene.add(hlight);        

            //Add some point lights to simulate real lights
            light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 1, 10000);
            light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
            scene.add(light);

            light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 1, 10000);
            light2.position.set(500, 100, 0);
            scene.add(light2);

            light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 1, 10000);
            light3.position.set(0, 100, -500);
            scene.add(light3);

            light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 1, 10000);
            light4.position.set(-500, 300, 0);
            scene.add(light4);


            controls.update();
            // Animation Script
            function animate() {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }

            // Setup GLTF Loader and load in obj
            let loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load('example.stl', function (geometry) {
                // console.log(gltf);
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: 0x171717,
                    shininess: 200
                });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                scene.add(mesh);
                renderer.render(scene, camera)
                animate();
            });


        }

        // Call method for starting init
        init();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
Example of my intended output, but in Fusion 360 instead of three.js (Note, the original file is a .stl but since three.js doesn't allow for part viewing, it is converted to .stl in the backend)
[image: fusion 360 ecample]
Example of the 'triangles' in a .stl file
[image: triangle example]

Comment: Your code example doesn't show code when you implement a raycaster to select the object, the raycaster also gives you the face. Then loop over all faces with common edges, and check if the face normal equals the clicked face normal. Than loop over faces with new common edges again, and again. This will give you the 'plane' as you call it. Although in three.js terminology a plane is something different....

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Thanks for your comment! It has given me a good insight in where to look next. What would you suggest as an alternative term for my so called 'planes'? I was aware that plane wasn't the correct term (see my quotes around the word when I used it) but I used it for lack of a better term.

(Just noticed I wasn't consistent with the quotes around plane, updated.)

Comment: Regarding the term: you are basically looking for a collection of `Faces`, where 1 `Face` is defined by 3 `Vectors` (and thus 3 `Edges`). A `Plane` is defined by a normal (`Vector` defining the tilt/rotation of the plane) and a constant (signed `Number` specifying the distance from plane to origin). Mathematically the plane is considered to be infinite, while the face is definitely not.